# Can anyone suggest the pattern of Initialization Vector for AES 128

Tags: encryption, aes

Can anyone suggest the pattern of Initialization vector for AES 128.

Can we include characters in IV or we have to include only numbers for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IV depends on the cipher mode. But for AES with CTR, CBC, and some other modes, use 16 bytes chosen by a cryptographic random number generator.